# Measuring time in omp_fn routines

Tags: gcc, openmp, disassembly, intel-pin

I am writing a pintool gathering metrics in a subset of applications routines(some among them, are generated by the compiler). 
The goal is to get the execution time of those routines.

Below is a set of attempts I already gave:

- Of course doing it with pin is a bad idea because of the Virtual Machine overhead.
- gcc option -finstrument-functions does not scope the OpenMP functions it generates.
- LD_PRELOAD does not work with OpenMP functions which are statically linked.
- Maybe if pin allowed to dump statically instrumented assembly, we could avoid the virtual environment overhead, but as far as I know it isn't possible.
- I know about Maqao instrumentation tool which do not use virtual environment, but I want to avoid using too many frameworks or translating my pintool into maqao lua script.

I guess I am left with manual binary instrumentation, but if anybody has a better solution, the help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the results - use a comprehensive measurement infrastructure that supports OpenMP such as Intel VTune, Extrae/Paraver, [Score-P](http://score-p.org). This will provide you profiling or tracing information about the OpenMP regions.

If you want to implement the measurement yourself, you can use the underlying source-to-source transformation tool [Opari](http://www.vi-hps.org/tools/opari2.html). You could also use the much cleaner [OpenMP tools interface (OMPT)](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/ompt-tr2.pdf), but AFAIK it is not widely supported yet. You might have some luck with recent Intel OpenMP runtimes.

Comment: I agree with the use of OMPT. This is one of the best ways of doing so. There are multiple other instrumentation libraries that support this. For example: Intel VTune, Extrae/Paraver, etc. Linux perf is also very useful, although it is difficult to disagregate metrics for each different threads.

Comment: Added VTune / Extrae. perf is a great tool in general, but has no notion of OpenMP and does not excel at distinguishing threads. Also the sampling approach will give limited accuracy regarding timing.

Comment: OMPT seems to be the best solution to avoid extra frameworks. Let me give it a try, and i'll give you my feedback.

Comment: The interface does not seem to be implemented yet. Is it ?

Comment: As I wrote, it's not widely supported yet. For instance you could check out https://github.com/OpenMPToolsInterface/LLVM-openmp

Comment: Edit: Intel compiler can have it: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-open-source-openmp-runtime-library/topic/635253
I am looking for a gcc implementation, I'll check out your link

Comment: The LLVM runtime Zulan pointed at is mostly compatible with GCC compiled code (there may be a few missing entrypoints associated with recently implemented tasking operations, but "classic" OpenMP code should be fine).